# need this item in table and border like this form

Tags: php, echo, counter

I need this item in table and border like this form:

```
$e = array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10", "item11", "item12");
$i = 0;
foreach ($e as $value) {
    $i++;
    if($i%3!=1)
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo $value;
    if($i%3!=1)
        echo "<br>";
}
```

I want the result to be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RrhX.png

Comment: Well nobody is stopping you sooooooo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way to wrap your already exist php code in table, try it:

```
$e = array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10", "item11", "item12");
$i = 0;
echo "<table border=1><tr>";    //tr to start the 1st row
foreach ($e as $value) {
    $i++;
    if ($i % 3 != 1)
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
    if ($i % 3 != 1)
        echo "</tr><tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
<table width="60%" border=1>        
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($e as $value) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

for above style -

```
$e = array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10", "item11", "item12");
?>
<table width="60%" border=1>  
<tr>      
<?php
$j = 0;
$i = 1;
while ($j < count($e)) {
     if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
     } else {
?> 
        <td><?php echo $e[$j];?></td>
<?php
        $j++;
     }
?>
<?php
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this result one cell in each row i want to be like image i added above

Answer (score 0):

this is simple in your code add table before the loop and close table tag after loop, then replace 
 by open/close tr tag and your spaces replace them by td with space tag and same for $value wrap it in td tag.

and as result you must get something like that:

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Item 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Item 6</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 7</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Item 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Item 9</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 10</td>
        <td colspan=2> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if this code is very easy so please send me the code php

Comment: your code is already do that, you must just wrap spaces/$value inside td, br replace it by tr tag, that's all.

Comment: 7a3mela w farjik kif laaa ma btezbat

Comment: <?php
    $e = array("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10", "item11", "item12");
    $i = 0;
     echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">';
    foreach ($e as $value) {
        $i++;
        if($i%3!=1)
            echo"<tr>";
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        if($i%3!=1)
            echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo'</table>';
    ?>

Comment: like this
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
item9
item10
item11
item12

Comment: you delete the spaces? you must keep them & wrap them in td just like $value.